# Data extraction and transform efficiency

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a Python script that connects to a MySQL database and executes a number of nested SELECT queries. It's basically a giant for loop. The database is structured such that Businesses have Menus, Menus have Sections, and Sections have Items. The script queries all the Businesses, and for each Business, it queries all of its Menus, and so on. It builds a big dictionary along the way that it then spits out as JSON.

It looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bottle import route, run
import mysql.connector
import json
import collections
import datetime

def getBusinesses():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="APIUser", password="abc123", host="12.34.56.78", port="54321", database="businesses")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    objects = {}

    businessesQuery = ("SELECT * FROM business")
    cursor.execute(businessesQuery)
    businessRows = cursor.fetchall()

    businessObjects = []
    for businessRow in businessRows:
        print businessRow[0]
        businessDict = collections.OrderedDict()
        businessDict['id'] = businessRow[0]
        businessDict['business_name'] = businessRow[1]
        businessDict['business_address1'] = businessRow[2]
        businessDict['business_address2'] = businessRow[3]
        businessDict['business_city'] = businessRow[4]
        businessDict['business_state'] = businessRow[5]
        businessDict['business_zip'] = businessRow[6]
        businessObjects.append(businessDict)

        menuQuery = ("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE business_id = %s" % businessRow[0])
        cursor.execute(menuQuery)
        menuRows = cursor.fetchall()

        menuObjects = []
        for menuRow in menuRows:
            menuDict = collections.OrderedDict()
            menuDict['id'] = menuRow[0]
            menuDict['menu_name'] = menuRow[1]
            menuDict['menu_description'] = menuRow[2]
            menuDict['menu_note'] = menuRow[3]
            menuDict['business_id'] = menuRow[4]
            menuObjects.append(menuDict)

        businessDict['menus'] = menuObjects

        for menuIdx, menuRow in enumerate(menuRows):
            sectionQuery = ("SELECT * FROM menu_section WHERE menu_id = %s" % menuRow[0])
            cursor.execute(sectionQuery)
            sectionRows = cursor.fetchall()

            sectionObjects = []
            for sectionIdx, sectionRow in enumerate(sectionRows):
                sectionDict = collections.OrderedDict()
                sectionDict['id'] = sectionRow[0]
                sectionDict['section_name'] = sectionRow[1]
                sectionDict['section_note'] = sectionRow[2]
                sectionDict['section_description'] = sectionRow[3]
                sectionDict['menu_id'] = sectionRow[4]
                sectionObjects.append(sectionDict)

                businessDict['menus'][menuIdx]['sections'] = sectionObjects

                itemQuery = ("SELECT * FROM menu_item WHERE section_id = %s" % sectionRow[0])
                cursor.execute(itemQuery)
                itemRows = cursor.fetchall()

                itemObjects = []
                for itemIdx, itemRow in enumerate(itemRows):
                    itemDict = collections.OrderedDict()
                    itemDict['id'] = itemRow[0]
                    itemDict['item_name'] = itemRow[1]
                    itemDict['item_description'] = itemRow[2]
                    itemDict['item_note'] = itemRow[3]
                    itemDict['item_price'] = itemRow[4]
                    itemDict['section_id'] = itemRow[5]
                    itemObjects.append(itemDict)

                    businessDict['menus'][menuIdx]['sections'][sectionIdx]['items'] = itemObjects


    objects['businesses'] = businessObjects
    return objects

@route('/test')
def index():
    return json.dumps(getBusinesses())

run(host='192.168.1.70', port=7070)
```

I want to know if this is an efficient way of doing things. When I deployed my database remotely (WebFaction) and ran the Bottle server locally, it took almost 40 seconds to return a few hundred rows. So it seems like something is amiss. I have a gut feeling that there could be a better way of doing this. Just not sure what that way is!

Comment: You should profile bits of the code to see what is taking the most time. If it is just the MySQL fetching, you could condense your queries into one large query that only gets executed once, then do the data handling on the python side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I had to venture a guess:  notice the rough structure of your code is:

```
def getBusinesses():
    businessesQuery = ("SELECT * FROM business")
    businessRows = cursor.fetchall()

    businessObjects = []
    for businessRow in businessRows:
        menuQuery = ("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE business_id = %s" % businessRow[0])
        menuRows = cursor.fetchall()


        for menuIdx, menuRow in enumerate(menuRows):
            sectionQuery = ("SELECT * FROM menu_section WHERE menu_id = %s" % menuRow[0])
            cursor.execute(sectionQuery)
            sectionRows = cursor.fetchall()

            sectionObjects = []
            for sectionIdx, sectionRow in enumerate(sectionRows):
                itemQuery = ("SELECT * FROM menu_item WHERE section_id = %s" % sectionRow[0])
                itemRows = cursor.fetchall()
```

That is, you execute nearly identical queries in a loop for `menu`, `menu_section` and especially `menu_item`.  Also, you're using `fetchall()` to return the full contents of the result set but examine each element only once, in a loop, where you create *another* list of objects.

what you might want instead is something more like:

```
businesses = []
cursor.execute("select * from business")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    business.append(...(row))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.execute("select * from menu")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    business[row['business_id']].menus.append(...(row))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.execute("select menu.business_id, menu_section.*"
               " from menu_section"
               " join menu on menu.id = menu_section.menu_id")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    business[row['business_id']][row['menu_id']].sections.append(...(row))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.execute("select menu.business_id, menu_section.menu_id, menu_item.*"
               " from menu_item"
               " join menu_section on menu_section.id = menu_item.section_id"
               " join menu on menu.id = menu_section.menu_id")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:        
    business[row['business_id']][row['menu_id']][row['section_id'].items.append(...(row))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

so that you're issuing a much smaller number of queries, and only loading the amount of data you can process in one go.

Comment: This was a huge help. I did a re-write, and the process went from 40 seconds down to 3. Thanks!